# magento my Account left sidebar add ,remove and rename tabs from admin panel

Tags: php, magento

in magneto i want to add ,remove and rename tabs from admin panel from my account left sidebar :

Like Add some new tabs , rename "Account Dashboard" to something else.

I want to do all this from admin so that my changes do not get lost from any update .plase tell better way to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename Account Dashboard and other links, add tabs and remove unused you can with own module that extends `Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation`. I think you need to read this article http://inchoo.net/magento/managing-navigation-links/ to realize customization for yourself